# Whitelisted IP has reset, how can I change it back?

Tags: mac, ip, ftp, osx-yosemite, whitelist

I (used to) have an IP address that had been whitelisted to access a website via FTP.  My IP has randomly been reset and I need to change it back so I can use FTP again.
I have the whitelisted IP documented, so how can I change my IP address to the documented one on Mac 10.10?

Comment: You can't.  You don't have a static ip address.  You will need to update the list of whitelisted addresses to access the website.

Answer (score 0):

I think most likely you'd have to contact your ISP but they may not support doing this.

You could try setting your IP address manually to be the one that you wrote down (i.e. go into your router / firewall and set it to use that instead of to obtain an IP automatically via DHCP), but it may not work as it may have already been assigned to another customer, and even if it hasn't, if you set it to that IP manually, it may get assigned to someone else in the future and then you'd have an IP conflict.

If the remote FTP access restriction permits doing so, you're better off going with a dynamic DNS solution with an automatic updater which keeps your IP current and then permitting access to the FTP via the hostname you get from a service like noip.com.